# Unable to upload multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 5`,`jquery` latest version.
I am trying to upload multiple files using `jquery fileupload` but I am unable to recieve multiple files.

**View:**

```
 <input id="fileupload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]"  >

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Media/UploadFiles',
            autoUpload: true,
            done: function (e, data) {

            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult UploadFiles()
        {

            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            { }
        }
```

Here in `Request.Files` I am recieving only one file.

Comment: Can you try uploading without jQuery plugin? I think your plugin is uploading them one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your uploaded files are actually sent one by one.

You can change your serve code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFiles()
{
    IList<string> filesSaved = new List<string>();

    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
    HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file];
    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = hpf.FileName;
        filesSaved.Add(fileName);
    }
    }

    return Json(new {files = filesSaved}, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

and insert a breakpoint and you will see that the request goes through once for each file you're sending.

The problem is in your client code. There's an option in that plugin `singleFileUploads` which defaults to `true`, as you can read [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#singlefileuploads).

You can change your client code setting `singleFileUploads: false` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Media/UploadFiles',
            autoUpload: true,
            singleFileUploads: false,
            done: function (e, data) {

            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        });
});
```

and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Big thanks, works like a charm..! But do you think this approach is the best option for uploading all types of media including (images,videos,audios etc).Also there are many great plugins available which have all the functionalities but I cannot use them since my requirement is a bit more customized.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this approach. You can check the type of media you're uploading on the server. In the web.config you can set the maximum size etc etc. These days I use [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) which is much easier and nicer to configure.